# How to add a Google Map to search results?

Tags: seo, google, map

How can I get a business map location displayed along with the Google search results page?

Answer (score 1):

Getting Google to display business map information is rather simple but can take some time to appear. Also, its worth mentioning that its not a guaranteed process as some search results have these options displayed especially with competing business names and businesses that use high volume everyday keywords. In order for Google to return the map information on your business name you need to give Google the right signals. You can give Google the right signals by registering your business on Google and various other citations sites across the globe, ideally local ones work best.

*Correction Information*

It's important that your (NAP) Name Address Phone Number is correct on all websites that contain your business information. Google has the ability to match details and in correct details won't hurt you but they won't help you either, so ensure all details are right on every site.

*Where to get Citations*

As with any backlink a citation mention has quality factors as well. You should see NAP as a backlink and you should aim for quality sites that could potential gain your a visitor.

Below is just some of the vast ways you can get citations by adding your business name, tel number and address.

Social sites:

- [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com)
- [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com)

Business Directory's

- [Yelp](http://www.yelp.co.uk)
- [Hotfog](http://www.hotfrog.co.uk/)

*Add your business to Google places*

In order for your map to be displayed your [business needs to be added to Google Places](http://www.google.co.uk/business), this process is takes around 7-21 days as Google will want to confirm your address by sending you a post card with a unique pin. All NAP data on Google places should match your NAP data on your citations sites. The more the merrier but stick to high quality citation sites and you can't go wrong.